# Knn using Cross Validation function

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, knn

I need to run the R code to find the `number of folder = 1` for `k=(c(1:12))` but the following warnings were displayed:

```
> warnings()
Mensagens de aviso:
1: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: k= 1 Error in x[1, 1] : subscript out of bounds

2: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: k= 2 Error in x[1, 1] : subscript out of bounds

3: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: k= 3 Error in x[1, 1] : subscript out of bounds

. . .

12: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: k=12 Error in x[1, 1] : subscript out of bounds

13: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  ... :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

This is a R code using `caret` package.

```
biopsy_final = na.omit(biopsy[,-c(1)]) # ID & NA excluded  

ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=1, repeats=1)
nn_grid <- expand.grid(k=c(1:12))
nn_grid

best_knn <- train(class~., data=biopsy_,
              method="knn",
              trControl=ctrl, 
              preProcess = c("center", "scale"),  # standardize
              tuneGrid=nn_grid)
print(best_knn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
grid <- expand.grid(k = 1:12)

{
  set.seed(1)

  index <- caret::createDataPartition(biopsy_$class, p = 0.75, list = FALSE) # partiotion test-train

  train <- biopsy_[index, ]
  test  <- biopsy_[-index, ]

  ctrl <- caret::trainControl(method  = "repeatedcv", 
                              number  = 10, # see this
                              repeats = 10   # see this
                              )  

  model <- caret::train(class~., 
                        data = train, 
                        method = "knn",
                        trControl = ctrl,
                        preProcess = c("center","scale"),
                        tuneGrid = grid)
}

# plot(model)
# model$bestTune # best k

# library(dplyr)
# predictions <- model %>% predict(test)
# RMSE(predictions, test$class)
```

Comment: This code is not ran. I've some warnings -->   Error: unexpected symbol in: " repeats = 1 classProbs" Error: unexpected ',' in " savePredictions = T," Error: unexpected ')' in " verboseIter = FALSE)" Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : argumento 'data' é do tipo errado > } Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Please, provide a fully reproducible example that I can adjust the code.

Comment: I modified the training control part. Look again.

Comment: I didn't understand why did you change the 'number' in trainControl and 'repeats = 4'? How can I get the test partition with only one element using K=1:12? Is it possible?

Comment: You're talking about different situations. `K = 1:12` means your set of possible neighbors. `repeats` is just the argument of how many times you will repeat your cross validation. I edited the answer, put `repeats = 10`, but that's up to you.

Comment: And the error in your code was in `number = 1`, which is referring to the number of partitions, folds.

Comment: I made mistakes on my arguments. So, in this particular case why can't I adjust the number to only one partition (number = 1)?

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to set up a cross validation, your fold number must be greater than 1. If it is 1, you will not cross validation.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable knowledge shared with us. It's pretty good to appreciate. So, if possible, can you show me an example that illustrates the cross validation with number = 1 is invalid?

Comment: This is intuitive. Think about it, if you have k = 1, there will never be cross-validation, since you will not have any folds left out.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27730/choice-of-k-in-k-fold-cross-validation